# grep entries from delimited text file and include it in another command

Tags: bash

I have database for persons and path to their files which stored on a computer. This data saved as (a very long) delimited text file as follows:

```
============
NAME: John
TIME: 12:31:25
PATH: ./a/b/v/c   #to some data related to the person
============
NAME: Jo
TIME: 11:21:11
PATH: ./c/s/d/f   #to some data related to the person 
============
NAME: Je
TIME: 10:51:15
PATH: ./q/n/h/l   #to some data related to the person
============

......  # very long list of entries in this format.
```

I want to create folder has the `NAME` of every entry and then copy all the stuff in his `PATH` to an `OUTPUT` folder.
I used `grep` in the code bellow to include the `PATH` for every person in the command `cp` then to copy all the stuff for all the `NAMES` at once?

```
#!/bin/bash -f
source=PATH TO THIS TEXT DELIMITED FILE (log.log)
grep -o 'NAME.*' ./log.log | cut -f2- -d':'> ./name.log; 
grep -o 'PATH.*' ./log.log | cut -f2- -d':'> ./path.log; 
for i in $(cat ./name.log);do
mkdir ./${i};
    for ii in $(cat ./path.log); do 
(
      cp ${ii}/*.* ./${i}
done
)&
done
```

Due to my shallow experience in coding I think I complicated this code. I need  suggestions to simplify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might try something like this...

First, use `awk` to dynamically generate a shell script:

```
awk '
  /NAME:/ {
    name=gensub(/\"/, "", "g", substr($0, 7))
  }
  /PATH:/ {path=$2}
  name && /=====/ {
    printf "mkdir \"%s\"\n", name
    printf "rsync -a \"%s/\" \"%s/\"\n", path, name
  }
'
```

Given your input, this would generate:

```
rsync -a "./a/b/v/c/" "John/"
rsync -a "./c/s/d/f/" "Jo/"
rsync -a "./q/n/h/l/" "Je/"
```

Then run that shell script.  You can combine this in a single operation:

```
awk '
  /NAME:/ {
    name=gensub(/\"/, "", "g", substr($0, 7))
  }
  /PATH:/ {path=$2}
  name && /=====/ {
    printf "mkdir \"%s\"\n", name
    printf "rsync -a \"%s/\" \"%s/\"\n", path, name
  }
'
```

I'm using `rsync` here for copying things, but of course you could just use `cp -r`.

Also, I notice that in your code you're using `*.*`.  That's probably not what you want, unless you mean, "only copy files that contain a dot somewhere in the filename".

**Update**

I've modified this so it works correctly given:

```
============
NAME: "John Frederick"
TIME: 12:31:25
PATH: ./a/b/v/c   #to some data related to the person
============
```

Comment: @Iarsaks. You are great. kindly I got this error : Unmatched '

Comment: There's nothing that should be generating that error.  [Here](https://asciinema.org/a/dyjsom8p469zh5ayn1un0d6p9) is a terminal session in which I run the above awk script against your data.  Are you able to run *just* the awk script (that is, do you only get the error when piping the output to `| sh`)?

Comment: Exactly! when I piping the output to |sh

Comment: Are all of your names single words?  Are there quotation marks in the data?

Comment: Yes there are quotation marks for some of it. The names are single word and some are two words

Comment: @Iarsks. It worked!! it look like a magic THANKS A LOT :)